# Backup and restore SQL Server Management Studio job schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-job

I've got a job in SQL Server Management Studio and I want to back up the schedule that it runs on so that the schedule can be applied to other jobs that I add. I know that I can get what I assume is the data I need to copy from using the following:

```
-- lists all aspects of the information for the job NightlyBackups.
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_help_job
    @job_name = N'NightlyBackups',
    @job_aspect = N'SCHEDULES' ;
GO
```

I'm just wondering how I can store the results of this stored procedure in a way that will allow me to add it to other jobs on the system. Preferably in T-SQL .

Answer (score 0):

The GUI method:
Right-click the job in SSMS and script it as CREATE; alter parameters to suit.

The T-SQL method:
I don't have that on-hand, but try opening Profiler, look for SQL:Completed and RPC:Completed, and then do the GUI method - you should capture the T-SQL that SSMS is executing!  Alter to suit.

Comment: Well, I _have_ the SQL that the job executes, I'm wondering how I can save the results of this. The `sp_help_job` stored procedure does a bunch of table joining to produce a table that contains all of the info. What I'm wondering is, how can I store this table so that I can then use `sp_update_job` to add the info to a different job in the future?